# How to resolve and deploy dependencies using Gradle with a Maven settings.xml file?

Tags: maven, gradle, continuous-integration

I would like to know if it's possible to resolve and deploy artifacts from/to a Maven repository using Gradle and a Maven `settings.xml` file. The repository is a secured one, so credentials are required in order to access it. Also, is it possible to specify the location of the `settings.xml` (I'm asking as we have a few different ones for different teams and we manage these through our CI server)?

A basic example would be really nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To fetch dependencies form a custom maven repo you can add/configure `repositories` like

```
repositories {
    maven {
        credentials {
            username 'user'
            password 'password'
        }
        url "http://repo.mycompany.com/maven2"
    }
}
```

To publish your artefacts you can look into `apply plugin: 'maven-publish'` plugin depending on which version of Gradle you are using.

And for configuring I think `net.linguica.maven-settings` is the plugin you can look into.

**Additional sources:**

[net.linguica.maven-settings](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/net.linguica.maven-settings?_ga=2.69149905.1382421951.1502290679-1697349971.1501156929)

[gradle repositories](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:repositories)

[maven publish plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/publishing_maven.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could adapt the code from the [maven-settings-decoder](https://github.com/jelmerk/maven-settings-decoder/blob/master/src/main/java/org/github/jelmerk/maven/settings/Decorder.java) to decrypt the passwords in maven settings files for usage in gradle.

It would be nice to turn this into a gradle plugin but that would create a chicken-or-egg problem where the plugin can't be downloaded from the repository because you don't yet have the password.